# Specific numbers of communities in leidenalg library igraph

Tags: python, graph, igraph

When I use `partition = la.find_partition(G)` and then `len(partition)` command on my graph, I get 402303 communities as the result.
I only want to have 15 communities, not 402303. 
Is there a way to find specific size communities in leidenalg library?

Comment: Iterate over the partitions, discarding those that do not meet your size criteria.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. That's a great idea but how can i discard them? is there a method for discarding?

Comment: The simplest way is to create a new list of partitions and ONLY copy the partitions into the new list if they meet your size criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_partition()` has a second required parameter, the `partition_type`. You must make an appropriate choice here, and also set the parameters of the partition type suitably.

A possible reason that you got so many partitions is that you may have chosen `CPMVertexPartition` and left the resolution parameter at the default of 1. The larger this value the more communities will be returned. With `CPMVertexPartition` a good starting point for experimentation is the graph density.

Or you can use `RBConfigurationVertexPartition` in which case a good starting point is 1.0 (which corresponds to maximizing the classic modularity).

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I did what you said, I used RBConfigurationVertexPartition but still I'm getting 401600 communities. I want to have at most 15 communities. Are there any other ways that i can get less communities? by aggregating or something like that.

Comment: As I said, you need to change the resolution parameter to change the number of communities. However, if you still get a very large number with RBConfigurationVertexPartition, or if the result is not responsive to the resolution parameter, then something is wrong with your data. If you can share a complete but _minimal_ example, someone might be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: How to get the corresponding nodes to the community numbers.